# Couchbase Lite alternative

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I have an `Android` project whose use `CouchBase lite 1.4` with `CouchDB` 
.We want to use the last `CouchBase lite` version but I have been reading this in the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/couchbase-lite/java.html) about `CouchBase Lite 2.0` :

> The new protocol is incompatible with CouchDB-based databases. And
>   since Couchbase Lite 2 only supports the new protocol, you will need
>   to run a version of Sync Gateway that supports it.

So I guess I have to migrate to Sync Gateway ?¿ as I can read [here](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/312):

> Couchbase Lite 2.0's enhanced replication protocol is not compatible
>   with CouchDB. The Sync Gateway 2.0 however will supporting both
>   Couchbase Lite 2.0 mobile clients with the new protocol and the
>   CouchDB enabled replication protocol.

My problem is that I have not clear what is Sync GatAway,becouse in some places you can read that works with CouchDB in other place I can read that does not work.

Comment: "How can I run a version of Sync Gateway?" Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: of course, quite confusing by the way

Comment: I was a bit confused by this: "...info about how to change from couchBase lite to Sync Gateway" I think you mean "change from CouchDB to Sync Gateway"?

Comment: thanks ....thanks a lot ...thank you so much

Comment: thanks ....thanks a lot ...thank you so much

Comment: there are a lot of people confused about it https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cbl-2-0-couchdb-server-syn-gateway/13362

Comment: in the order hand you can read this : https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/312

Comment: @chintan-mishra That is correct. Couchbase Lite 2.0's enhanced replication protocol is not compatible with CouchDB .
The Sync Gateway 2.0 however will supporting both Couchbase Lite 2.0 mobile clients with the new protocol and the CouchDB enabled replication protocol.

However, the suggestion to keep large attachments in a separate store and store the URL in the document is still a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cloudant Sync for Android](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) as an alternative. 
It is compatible with your CouchDB installation or with IBM's Cloudant NoSQL service.

We are using this library in some mobile projects based on Android.

Comment: gracias Juanjo, I am going to take a look :)

Comment: ostras como se han puesto esto :( ... nos han frito a negativos :(